# How to load picture into Flowlayoutpanel without Openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net, flowlayoutpanel

I am still unable to find this solutions, could you please help me that would be great for me. Actually I want to load picture into Flowlayoutpanel without Openfiledialog, whenever I want to run the application it automatically load picture from given file path.

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        Dim TheFilePath As String
        Dim F as string = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "C:\Users\Mohammed Waseem\Pictures\", "*.jpg")
        Dim fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog
        If fbd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            TheFilePath = fbd.SelectedPath
            Try
            For Each F As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath)
                Dim NewImage As Image = Image.FromFile(F)
                NewImage = NewImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewImage.Width * 0.5, NewImage.Height * 0.5, AddressOf abort, System.IntPtr.Zero)
                Dim P As New PictureBox
                P.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
                P.Image = NewImage
                AddHandler P.Click, AddressOf PictureBox1_Click
                FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(P)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(F))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
Private Function abort() As Boolean
    Return False
End Function
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Dim strFileName As String = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Tag.ToString
    MsgBox(strFileName.ToString)
    Process.Start(strFileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know where these Images are stored? If so, the just `Directory.GetFiles("[The Path where the Images are stored]", "*.jpg")`. You show a `FolderBrowserDialog` when you need a User to specify this path. If you already know it... If you don't, you'll have to ask. If the Path is a known path, as `My Pictures` (localized), see [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using your hard-coded folder:

```
Dim ImageExtension As String = "*.jpg"
Dim FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\Mohammed Waseem\Pictures\"
For Each FilePath As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath, ImageExtension)
    Try
        Dim NewImage As Image = Image.FromFile(FilePath)
        NewImage = NewImage.GetThumbnailImage(NewImage.Width * 0.5, NewImage.Height * 0.5, AddressOf abort, System.IntPtr.Zero)

        Dim P As New PictureBox
        P.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        P.Image = NewImage
        AddHandler P.Click, AddressOf PictureBox1_Click

        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(P)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath))
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
Next
```